# Using decorators for AssertionError exception handling in Python

Tags: python, exception, decorator, python-decorators, assertion

This is my first question here, please tell me whether it is asked properly . :x

I am trying to understand Python AssertionError exception handling and decorators better, and I wonder whether I could replace a series of nested try/except/else blocks within a function by decorators…

**EXAMPLE:**
**What I would usually do:**

```
# CHECK functions:
def is_int(x):
    assert isinstance(x,int), f"'{x}' is not an integer"
    return True

def is_str(y):
    assert isinstance(y,str), f"'{y}' is not a string"
    return True


# FUNCTION I want to decorate 
def pretty_function(x:int, y:str):
    try:
        is_int(x) 
    except AssertionError as exc:
        print(exc)
    else:
        try:
            is_str(y) 
        except AssertionError as exc:
            print(exc)
        else:
            print(f'There is/are {x} {y}')
```

Input:

```
pretty_function(2,'cat')
pretty_function(2,3)
pretty_function('2','cat')
```

Output:

```
There is/are 2 cat
'3' is not a string
'2' is not an integer
```

So this is working fine, but I would like to use decorators instead... especially when I have more than 2 nested try/except/else blocks.

**What I would like to do:**

```
# DECORATOR ---> Don't know how to make it work as I want
def test_assertion(test_function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            test_function(*args, **kwargs)
        except AssertionError as exc:
            print(exc)
        else:
            return test_function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


# CHECK functions --> No idea how to write these correctly
@test_assertion
def is_int(func):
    def wrapper(x):
        assert isinstance(x,int), f"'{x}' is not an integer"
        return True
    return wrapper

@test_assertion
def is_str(func):
    def wrapper(y):
        assert isinstance(y,str), f"'{y}' is not a string"
        return True
    return wrapper


# FUNCTION I want to decorate 
@is_int(x)
@is_str(y)
def pretty_function(x:int, y:str):
    print(f'There is/are {x} {y}')
```

Input:

```py
pretty_function(2,'cat')
pretty_function(2,3)
pretty_function('2','cat')
```

Output:

```py
# What I get so far:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    /var/folders/r9/nj5lw_gj0fvfp4bsmcy587ch0000gn/T/ipykernel_2388/1180576500.py in <module>
     28 
     29 # FUNCTION I want to decorate
---> 30 @is_int(x)
     31 @is_str(y)
     32 def pretty_function(x:int, y:str):
    
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

So my experimental code doesn’t work… :'(
The first decorator however seems to work:
If I simply type:

```py
# DECORATOR 
def test_assertion(test_function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            test_function(*args, **kwargs)
        except AssertionError as exc:
            print(exc)
        else:
            return test_function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


# CHECK functions 
@test_assertion
def is_int(x):
    assert isinstance(x,int), f"'{x}' is not an integer"
    return True

@test_assertion
def is_str(y):
    assert isinstance(y,str), f"'{y}' is not a string"
    return True
```

Input:

```py
print(is_int(2))
print(is_int('2'))
print(is_str(2))
print(is_str('2'))
```

I get this output:

```py
True
'2' is not an integer
None
'2' is not a string
None
True
```

The thing is, so far I only found situations in which the else statement is absent... and situations that are too complicated to understand for a beginner. :/

Any idea?

Comment: It cannot be simple 1/`@is_int(x)`  is not a valid statement if x is not defined 2/ even if it was one, or you accept something like `@is_int('x')`, you have to extract the name of the function's arguments in the function's definition

Answer (score 0):

One issue is your decorators don't know what `x` and `y` are in advance. This can be sorted using `'x'` and `'y'`, instead of `x` and `y`. However, it will be much simpler if you modify the function signature as well, to enforce the arguments to be `keyword only`.
One method will be:

```
def assert_type(kwd, _type):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(**kwargs):
            assert isinstance(kwargs[kwd], _type), f"{kwargs[kwd]} not a {_type.__name__}"
            return func(**kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@assert_type('x', int)
@assert_type('y', str)
def pretty_function(*, x:int, y:str):
    print(f'There is/are {x} {y}')
```

Something more general will be:

```
def assert_types(**mapping):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(**kwargs):
            for kwd, _type in mapping.items():
                assert isinstance(kwargs[kwd], _type), f"{kwargs[kwd]} not a {_type.__name__}"
            return func(**kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@assert_types(x=int, y=str)
def pretty_function(*, x:int, y:str):
    print(f'There is/are {x} {y}')
```

Then you call:

```
pretty_function(x=2,y='cat')
pretty_function(x=2,y=3)
pretty_function(x='2',y='cat')
```

---

To get your desired program behavior (you will still have to use `'x'` and `'y'`), you can use `__annotations__` attribute of the function, to get the names of args.

```
from functools import wraps
def is_int(arg):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            params = (*args, *kwargs.values())
            mapping = dict(zip(func.__annotations__, params))
            assert isinstance(mapping[arg], int), f"{mapping[arg]} not an integer"
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

def is_str(arg):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            params = (*args, *kwargs.values())
            mapping = dict(zip(func.__annotations__, params))
            assert isinstance(mapping[arg], str), f"{mapping[arg]} not a string"
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@is_int('x')
@is_str('y')
def pretty_function(x:int, y:str):
    print(f'There is/are {x} {y}')
```

If you are prepared to use `inspect.signature`, then you can also use the following:

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature

def assert_types(**type_mapping):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            params = signature(func).bind(*args, **kwargs).arguments
            for argname, val in params.items():
                _type = type_mapping[argname]
                assert isinstance(val, _type), f"{val!r} is not {_type.__name__}"
            return func(**kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@assert_types(x=int, y=str)
def pretty_function(x:int, y:str):
    print(f'There is/are {x} {y}')
```